# why React production build only shows the 404 page without the rest of the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I created a website with react and I'm using react-router-dom I want to deploy it to netlify, so i run npm run build but when I click the index.html. It only shows the route I created for the non-existing path i.e 404 page, How do I go about displaying the Homepage and the rest of the page?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `netlify.toml` file to the root of your project and add the following lines. Then re-deploy on Netlify.

[Redirects and rewrites](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/)

This is necessary to instruct netlify to redirect all routes to your app. So that react-router-dom can handle routing internally.

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```